# Infinite rooms and doors (2)

Tags: graph-theory, infinitary-combinatorics

> Suppose we have a house (with finitely many rooms) in which every room has an even number of doors. Prove that the number of doors from the house to the outside world is also even.

All I could figure out up till now, is that each door connects 2 rooms.

Can we prove this without using graph theory? (Graph theory answers will do just fine though).

I don't want complete answers ... just hints.

Comment: Separate the doors into two types, $I$ for internal and $E$ for external.  Show that $\sum n_i = 2I+E$, where $n_i$ is the number of doors out of room $i$.

Comment: Can you tell me how to write, "how we got to $2I$" formally?

Comment: Sure.  Every internal door appears in exactly two rooms, hence it occurs exactly twice in the sum.  If you want something more formal than that, I'd do it by induction on the number of internal doors.  Obvious if $I=0$, say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [handshaking lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking_lemma) will do nicely. If we think of the outside as just another (very large) room, then each room is a vertex, each door is an edge, and apart from the outside room, each vertex has an even number of edges.